# Box API file upload 400 bad request

Tags: java, api, upload, box

I have a problem using the file upload Box API. I'm using Java with the Apache HttpClient (4.4). As far as I can tell, I am setting everything correctly, but I always get a 400 Bad request response.

I can provide more details if necessary, but here is the debug output that includes the request and response data as seen by the HttpClient:

```
http-outgoing-2 >> POST /api/2.0/files/content HTTP/1.1
http-outgoing-2 >> Authorization: Bearer taMJdbLcm1gJmTdnUUctqU53lpRXlVEi
http-outgoing-2 >> Content-Length: 506
http-outgoing-2 >> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=NMMQjAsnXwlKj02hT5qkfGNSn7hoOE1T1nGpaV52
http-outgoing-2 >> Host: upload.box.com
http-outgoing-2 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
http-outgoing-2 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4 (Java 1.5 minimum; Java/1.7.0_79)
http-outgoing-2 >> Cookie: box_visitor_id=55b9188c8618a3.22188589
http-outgoing-2 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
http-outgoing-2 >> "POST /api/2.0/files/content HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "Authorization: Bearer taMJdbLcm1gJmTdnUUctqU53lpRXlVEi[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "Content-Length: 506[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=NMMQjAsnXwlKj02hT5qkfGNSn7hoOE1T1nGpaV52[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "Host: upload.box.com[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4 (Java 1.5 minimum; Java/1.7.0_79)[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "Cookie: box_visitor_id=55b9188c8618a3.22188589[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "--NMMQjAsnXwlKj02hT5qkfGNSn7hoOE1T1nGpaV52[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attributes"[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "{"name":"This-is-a-Temp-File1438193805638", "parent":{"id":"4108964579"}}"
http-outgoing-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "--NMMQjAsnXwlKj02hT5qkfGNSn7hoOE1T1nGpaV52[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "Content-Type: application/octet-stream[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "this is a test file for upload1438193805640"
http-outgoing-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 >> "--NMMQjAsnXwlKj02hT5qkfGNSn7hoOE1T1nGpaV52--[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 << "Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 << "Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 18:16:45 GMT[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 << "Age: 0[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 << "Server: ATS[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 << "[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-2 << HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
http-outgoing-2 << Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
http-outgoing-2 << Content-Length: 0
http-outgoing-2 << Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 18:16:45 GMT
http-outgoing-2 << Age: 0
http-outgoing-2 << Connection: keep-alive
http-outgoing-2 << Server: ATS
```

Can anyone see where the problem lies? Thanks for any help, Martin

Answer (score 0):

In your second mime chunk you have said the content type is binary but your data is actually text. This could be one issue with the request.